# How to access POST parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to learn symfony PHP framework but unlike Ruby on Rails it is not really intuitive.

I'm rendering a form with newAction that looks like this

```
public function newAction()
        {   
            $product = new Product();
            $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);


                    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
                            'form' => $form->createView()
                        ));
        }
```

it renders very simple form:

```
<form action="{{ path("AcmeStoreBundle_default_create") }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} class="blogger">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {{ form_row(form.price) }}
        {{ form_row(form.name) }}
        {{ form_row(form.description) }}

        {{ form_rest(form) }}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

That points to the 'create' action:

```
public function createAction()
        {
            $product = new Product();
            $product->setName('A Foo Bar');
            $product->setPrice('19.99');
            $product->setDescription('Lorem ipsum dolor');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();


        return $this->redirect("/show/{$product->getId()}");
        }
```

Right now this action only saves the same static values, but i would like it to access data from the form above. My question is very easy (i hope). How can i save this previously sent informations ie how can i get POST parameters inside createAction?

Answer (score 2):

No need for two actions, you can add this in the same action newAction

```
public function newAction()
        {   
            $product = new Product();
            $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $request =  $this->getRequest();

        if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
            $form->bindRequest($request);/*or  $form->handleRequest($request); depends on symfony version */
            if ($form->isValid()) {
              $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();
       return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_route'),array(params));
           }
       }
  return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
                            'form' => $form->createView()
                        ));
}
```

Comment: ok, thx, but what if i need to do it with two actions anyway, can you show me how?

Comment: The best way is to do it in the same action, that's what I use as a solution. I edited my answer to fit your request up.

Comment: ok, but pls tell me why didnt you define $em? what is it here? as far as I can see you just call persist() method on it

Comment: $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

Comment: Note: `$this->getRequest()` Will be removed in future versions of Symfony2. Try not to use it anymore. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2e07338c5c58184318812f3852766a961b973df9

Answer (score 1):

Something that can help you :

http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/04/symfony2-crud-generator/

Very useful short videos that explain how to use CRUD generator command lines. And then if you use CRUD generator which is in Symfony2 by default, you will have your action newAction self created and you'll be able to read code generated (best practice code with your symfony version) and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood you:

```
// ...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...

public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect("/show/{$product->getId()}");
    }


    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView()
                ));
}
```

And here is the [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions) to doc page.
If you need directly get some request parameter you can use `$request->request->get('your_parameter_name');` for `POST` and `$request->query->get('your_parameter_name');` for `GET`.

Also you can get your form data like: `$form->get('your_parameter_name')->getData();`.

By the way, as mentioned above, you don't need two actions.

Comment: i believe dividing this into two seperate actions makes everything more elegant, less logic (if method == post) in controller is always better

Comment: @Leo you don't need to check whether the method is POST. Read the doc.